# Image not centered

Tags: php, html, css

I have a `loginPage.php` file that goes as:

```
<?php 
    //some php stuff
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form Design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylelogin.css">
<body>
....and so on
```

My `stylelogin.css` file goes as:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(image1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.loginbox{
...and so on
```

**Issue**

[image]

This is what my login page looks like. Please note the image in background. It isn't centered, while I assumed that the css script would be doing this job. Also, if I press the `Login` button with incorrect credentials, and hence getting back to this page itself but after a reload, the image is then centered (pic below). Please help me understand what am I doing wrong, and why the `body` section in `stylelogin.css` not doing the required thing. Thanks...

[image]

**Edit**

`background-size: 100vh 100vw;` gives:

[image]

Comment: You are missing `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: @LuísP.A. I tried that, but it removes the lower section in the first pic and replaces it with white screen space

Comment: Try `background-size: 100vh 100vw; or you need to set body to 100%

Comment: @LuísP.A. It doesn't work. I have not even used this before, so I don't know if some modification of this would help. But not this one as such. I have editted my question to add the output for your reference

Comment: Set body height to 100%

Comment: @LuísP.A. setting body to 100% gives result of 1st pic without 100vh 100vw, and 
of 3rd pic with them

Comment: Don´t forget the no-repeat

Comment: I need to check you code (html, and CSS) to be more helpful..  Make your code on a jsfiddle

Comment: @LuísP.A. doing the `height/size + no repeat` thing still gives same as 1st pic

Comment: @LuísP.A. sure, please wait a min. Thank you

Comment: @LuísP.A. since I was using php, I changed my file to html file, deleting all the database related code, and strangely, I'm getting a perfect right now, as I should get......

Comment: So maybe is a html syntax error... you need to check your html with injected php code

Comment: @LuísP.A. but when why would it give correct result after reloading (as I mention in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
body {
        background: url(nohisto/media/test.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: It works. Can you please explain the middle 3 lines in your code a bit?

Comment: Adds support for different browsers